# Passport and ExpressJS, route function not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Im using passport for some admin authentication but the redirect seems to not be calling me function. As a result all that gets printed on login is [object Object]

My code:
Routes

```
app.get('/admin', isLoggedIn, Routes.admin);
        app.get('/login', Routes.adminLogin);
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/admin',
            failureRedirect : '/login'
        }));
```

Passport setup

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
        passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
            done(null, user._id);
        });
        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
            user.getCollection().findById(id)
            .on('success', function(doc){done(doc)});
        });
        passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        }, function(req,username,password,done){
            user.getName(username)
            .on('success', function(doc){
                if(doc == null || doc.password != password) {return done(null, false, "Invalid password");}
                return done(null, doc);
            })
            .on('error', function(err){return done(err);});
        }));
    };
```

Admin route :

```
var adminRoute = exports.adminRoute = function(req,res){
        console.log(" ADMIN PAGE");
        res.render('admin.jade');
    };
```

Comment: What does your adminLogin route/controller look like?

Comment: It just renders the login page. Nothing else atm.

Comment: Your `deserializeUser` is faulty, it passes `doc` as first argument to `done`, instead of the second: `done(null, doc)`. Don't know if that's the cause of your problem though.

Comment: It looks like you have named your admin page route `adminRoute`, while your redirect is looking for just `admin`.

Comment: I can see how that may be confusing, I have my routes aliased to a Routes object thats not included here. @robertklep was right about the null thing. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) was right, passing `null` as the first argument in done inside deserializeUser worked.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
            user.getCollection().findById(id)
            .on('success', function(doc){done(null,doc)});
        });
```